# how to fix PHP XML sitemap encoding error

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Am creating XML sitemap using PHP. The XML values are from database and using below code to generate XML sitemap.

```
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.PHP_EOL;

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `tbl_city_landing_pages` WHERE `city_landing_pages_status` = 1 ORDER BY `city_landing_pages_keyword` ASC");
$total = mysqli_num_rows($query);

echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">'.PHP_EOL;

while ($city_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<url>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '<loc>'.BX_DOL_URL_ROOT.strtolower(str_replace(array(" ", "/"), array("-", "_"), $city_rows["city_landing_pages_keyword"])).'</loc>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '<lastmod>'.date('Y-m-d').'</lastmod>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '</url>'.PHP_EOL;
}

echo '</urlset>'.PHP_EOL;
```

The above code is working fine with some characters.

In my DB some row contains **Bogotá, D.C.**. And this character is not encoding even charset is utf-8. And the error shown is,

**This page contains the following errors:**

**error on line 19 at column 6: Encoding error**

**Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

How to show all the text from DB.

Is there any solution for this. I need to display all the values from mysql DB.

Comment: Is your database connection set to use UTF-8? How about the columns / tables?

Comment: @Phil database is set to UTF-8

Comment: That's a very general response. I asked you about three very separate things. If you could, please show where you're setting the connection encoding, ie [`mysqli_set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Comment: I said about database collation utf8_general_ci

Comment: So are you setting your connection encoding via `mysqli_set_charset()` or not? You should also check out [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have character encoding issues.

Try this approach,

- First, identify columns that can produce results with different
  character sets.
- Wrap them with `utf8_encode` before adding to the `XML` node.
- In your example above, let's say this is the column (`$city_rows["city_landing_pages_keyword"]`), that brings different character sets. Wrap them with `utf8_encode` before placing in the `XML`. See below,

`echo '<loc>'.BX_DOL_URL_ROOT.strtolower(str_replace(array(" ", "/"), array("-", "_"), utf8_encode($city_rows["city_landing_pages_keyword"]))).'</loc>'.PHP_EOL;`

Likewise, do for the rest of the columns that can bring results with different character sets.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: I am glad it worked and it was a pleasure helping you :)